# g++ project compilation with boost unit test

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I'm trying to compile unit test (boost) on Linux but compiler thows an error. 
Could someone check my command?

```
g++ -o UTest ../UTest/UT1.cpp ../UTest/UT2.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_unit_test_framework
```

**Error**

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
```

I removed `main()` from g++ comand because it should not be used when `boost unit test` is used.

What's wrong?

PS The project without unit tests (with `main()`) is compiled fine. Unit tests on Windows work fine also.

**Update**

The issue with `main()` is resolved. But a new one has born.

Both `UT1.cpp` and `UT2.cpp` has included `UTCommon.h` and now I have lots error like the following

**Error**

```
tmp2.cpp:(.text+0xd44a): multiple definition of `boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::operator<<(boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream const&)'
/tmp/cc0jw8uR.o:tmp.cpp:(.text+0xd44a): first defined here
/tmp/cctLn9QJ.o: In function `boost::test_tools::tt_detail::equal_impl(char const*, char const*)'
```

**UTCommon.h**

```
#ifndef UT_COMMON_H
#define UT_COMMON_H

#ifndef BOOST_TEST_MODULE
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE UnitTest
#endif

#if defined (__GNUC__) && defined(__unix__)
    #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#elif defined (WIN32)
    #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: You *MUST* have *SOME* "main()" function in your program!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best create a separate .cpp file that includes the file `boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp`. This will include an pre-generated `main()` function in your code. You can then use the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` macro for the actual tests (as many times as you like):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK        // this is optional
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest   // specify the name of your test module
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>  // include this to get main()


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(my_test_1)    // specify a test case
{
  /* Test something... */
  const static auto expected = 12;
  auto actual = my_func();

  BOOST_CHECK(actual == expected);
}
```

Compile this .cpp file (add linker options as necessary for all the functions defined in your own code), and it will become an executable that performs all the tests and generates a report.

Comment: Thanks so much, this simple example is compiled. The issue was with `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`. I used `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>` in Windows and all worked fine, but in Linus this doesn't work. Please, look at my updated question.

Comment: Is the command line you use to build (in the old part of the question) still up to date? The new error message mentions `UT_Math.obj`, but that isn't in your build command. Where does this come from?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the error (previous was from windows compilation). I just created 2 files `tmp.cpp` and `tmp2.cpp` with your  simple code example and inluded `UTCommon.h`

Comment: I believe the issue is in including `UTCommon.h` multiple times. Because separatelly `tmp.cpp` and `tmp2.cpp` compilations are fine

Comment: @Torrius Ah. In the original build command, you had _both_ `UT1.cpp` and `UT2.cpp` included in one compile/link command. If you do the same with `tmp.cpp` and `tmp2.cpp` now, it won't work because each of them includes a definition for `main` (imported from the boost unit test header file). If you have two .cpp files each with their own definition of main (or if they share any other function name), you must compile and link them separately.

Comment: This why many people use Makefiles and the like to do the building. With multiple files you end up needing many build commands and you don't want to have to enter them all manually. Best use a simple Makefile or something similar to define the build commands for each module.

Comment: Makefile also doesn't help. The same errors during 
`tmp: tmp.o tmp2.o` with rule `g++ tmp.o tmp2.o -o tmp`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20058/discussion-between-jogojapan-and-torrius)

Comment: The 2nd isssue is fixed by merging `tmp.cpp` and `tmp2.cpp` into one file