# Where do I find out how to link boost libraries?

Tags: boost

I'm currently trying to link a unit test using the boost unit testing framework. When it came to compiling my code, I immediately found myself googling "how to link boost unit tests", and sure enough, someone has had [that same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547771/g-project-compilation-with-boost-unit-test).

But the fact that I've used a library for over a year now, frequently visit the documentation, and still don't know where to find the linker flags is a terrible thing. I've read the [boost documentation which ostensibly answers this question](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), but didn't find the answer there.

If I want to build my program using `boost library x`, how do I find out which flag to give the linker to actually link it?

Answer (score 1):

Most Boost libraries are header only, so all you have to do is `#include` them in your code and tell the compiler where to find them (`-I`).  For those that actually need linking, your linker flags are where to find the lib (`-L`) and what to link (for library `libx` use the linker flag `-lx`)

Comment: You're right. This answer would be better suited as a comment.